# Question related to non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am facing a problem in this question.

> Let $y$ be fixed. Prove that $x \geq y$ implies $Ax \geq y$ for all $x$ if and only if $A \geq 0$ and $Ay \geq y$.

A≥0 implies each entry in the matrix A is non-negative and x≥y  means each entry in x is greater than or equal to corresponding entry in y.   x and y are column vectors.

Comment: Could you precise your assumptions? Where do $x,y,A$ live? What does $x\geq y$ mean? I have an idea, but I think it would be better to include it in the question.

Comment: x  and y are  n-dimensional column vector. A is n-cross-n matrix.       x≥y implies that each entry of x-y is non-negative.

Comment: This still leaves open what $x\geq y$ and $A\geq 0$ mean for you. And all this should be stated in the question.

Comment: I am giving an example.Let x=[9 5 7]' and y =[ 1 3 4]' then  x≥y . Additionally  A≥0 means each entry in the matrix A is non-negative.

Comment: Please write all this in the question. An note that an example does not suffice for a definition. Also note that it is very common for lots of people to interpret $A\geq 0$ as $A$ is self-adjoint with nonnegative spectrum. So definitions are really needed here.

Comment: I am really sorry for this. And thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the equivalence can be proved as follows.

$\Rightarrow$: Suppose that $A \geq 0$ and $Ay \geq y$. Let $x\ge y$. Then $Ax\ge Ay\ge y$.

$\Leftarrow$: Suppose that $x \geq y$ implies $Ax \geq y$ for all $x$. Suppose that the matrix $A$ has a negative element $a_{ij}$. Let $e_j$ be a $n$-dimesional vector having the $j$-th coordinate equal to $1$ and other coordinates equal to 0. Let $\lambda>\max\{0,(Ay-y)_i/|a_{ij}|\}$. Put $x=y+\lambda e_j$. Then $x\ge y$, but $(Ax)_i<y_i$, a contradiction. Hence $A\ge 0$.

Since $y\ge y,$ we see that $Ay\ge y$.

Comment: Thank you so much....I am highly grateful to you.